# PhantomJS page.evaluate isn't executed

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS to open a url of a certain login page, fill in the user/password, and click the login button.
When tried on Facebook, it worked fine. But when tried on my webpage, page.evaluate() was simply not executed.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "http://www.facebook.com";

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

page.open(url, function() {
    page.render("phase1.png");
    page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log("test");
        document.getElementById("email").value = "email";
        document.getElementById("pass").value = "password";
    });
    page.render("phase2.png");
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("loginbutton").click();
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render("phase3.png");
        phantom.exit();
    }, 2000);
});
```

This is my code when I use it to log in to Facebook. Using the rendered images, I can see that it works.
To use it on my webpage, I just replace the url and the element IDs. The page is opened (visible on the rendered image), but page.evaluate() isn't executed (The string "test" isn't printed to the console, all 3 images are the same - empty login page). What could be the reason for that? Note that there's no redirection.

Comment: Subscribe to page.onError callback, are there any errors?

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible what you describe. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. PhantomJS 2.x is known to hide some errors. You can try PhantomJS 1.9.8, too, for good measure.

Comment: I registered to those events, and nothing was printed to console. 
However, when I tried version 1.9.8 as you suggested (I was using 2.1.1), page.evaluate() was executed. I am now trying to figure out what is the difference between the versions that's relevant to this case...